# I am having problem while using filter in react Hooks,how can i solve this issue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, rxjs, frontend

I tried to use filter in react Hooks for filtering the state data fetched from the API but i get an empty array as output.How can i solve this issue?Following below is my code:

```
let FinalData = Data.filter((item) => item.district).map((item) => item.district);
let Testdata = District.filter((item) => item.title_ne === FinalData).map((item) => 
item.centroid.coordinates);
console.log("finaldata>>>", FinalData);
console.log("Districts>>>", District);
console.log("data>>>", Data);
console.log("Finally>>>", Testdata);
```

In every console.log i get the state value but in ' console.log("Finally>>>", Testdata);' i get output as empty array.How can i solve this issue?

Following are my output:
[image]

Comment: `let FinalData = Data.filter((item) => item.district).map((item) => item.district);` returns an array. So, `District.filter((item) => item.title_ne === FinalData)` will be an empty array.

Comment: As @HarshaVenkatram said, FinalData is an array.

You probably want to do `let Testdata = District.filter((item) => FinalData.some((district_name) => district_name === item.title_ne).map((item) => item.centroid.coordinates);
`

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to find the title items with same titles in FinalData data you can do it like this :

```
let FinalData = Data.filter((item) => item.district).map((item) => item.district);
let Testdata = District.reduce((all,item) => FinalData.some(title=>item.title_ne===title)?[...all,item.centroid.coordinates]:all,[]);
console.log("finaldata>>>", FinalData);
console.log("Districts>>>", District);
console.log("data>>>", Data);
console.log("Finally>>>", Testdata);
```

use array `reduce` method instead of `filter` and `map` chain